# How to display entities which have list values in the html table

Tags: html, angular-material

I have entities that have to be displayed in the html table. But these entities have lists in it. And these lists have to be displayed in the same table as well.

This is the example of the table that i want to get:

https://github.com/dariapopova13/AvtodoriaTest/blob/master/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_001.png?raw=true

Example of the entity that must be displayed:

```
export class Section extends AbstractIdEntity{
  name:string;
  group: ZoneGroup;
  zones:SimpleRegZone[]
}
```

Example of the list entity:

```
export class SimpleRegZone extends AbstractIdEntity {
  name: string;
  status: DictEntity;
  speedLimitType: DictEntity;
  zoneVersion: String;
  lanesNumber: number;
}
```